# WinAPI, окно предпросмотра скринсейвера не получает сообщения о выходе

Tags: c++, winapi

Точнее, оно вообще не получает сообщений. Если запускать в обычном режиме, всё прекрасно работает и закрывается, если дёрнуть мышью. А если запускать в режиме предпросмотра, то тоже всё прекрасно работает, но процесс остаётся висеть после закрытия диалогового окна. Скомпилировал так, чтобы открывалась консоль и выводилось MSG на каждый месседж. В предпросмотре консоль пуста. ЧЯДНТ?

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/wglew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "colors.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    printf("MSG\n");
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CLOSE:
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR cmd,int) {
    wglewInit();
    glewInit();
    HWND hwnd=0;

    char* s;
    int i,W,H;
    for (i=0,s=strtok(cmd," \t\n");s;s=strtok(NULL," \t\n"),i++) if (i==0) {
        if (strcmp(s,"/s")&&strcmp(s,"/S")&&strcmp(s,"/p")&&strcmp(s,"/P")) return 0;
    } else if (i==1) {
        if (!(hwnd=(HWND)atoi(s))) return 0;
    } else return 0;

    if (!hwnd) { //fullscreen mode
        WNDCLASS wc;
        memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
        wc.style= CS_OWNDC;
        wc.lpfnWndProc=EmptyProc;
        wc.hInstance= hinst;
        wc.hIcon= LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wc.lpszClassName= "SSCN";
        RegisterClass(&wc);
        W=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        H=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        hwnd = CreateWindow("SSCN","",WS_VISIBLE|WS_POPUP|WS_SYSMENU,0,0,W,H,NULL, NULL, hinst, NULL);
        SetCursor(NULL);
    } else { //preview mode
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)&WndProc);
        RECT t;
        GetClientRect(hwnd,&t);
        W=t.right-t.left; H=t.bottom-t.top;
    }

    // make window accessible for OpenGL
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    memset(&pfd,0,sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nSize=sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion=1;
    pfd.dwFlags=PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType=PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits=32;
    pfd.cDepthBits=24;
    pfd.cStencilBits=8;
    pfd.iLayerType=PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    HDC dc=GetDC(hwnd);
    SetPixelFormat(dc,ChoosePixelFormat(dc,&pfd),&pfd);
    HGLRC rc=wglCreateContext(dc);
    wglMakeCurrent(dc,rc);

    glClearColor(0,0.3,0.3,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SwapBuffers(dc);

    MSG Msg;
    clock_t time=clock();
    while (clock()-time<CLOCKS_PER_SEC/10) 
        PeekMessage(&Msg,NULL, 0, 0,PM_REMOVE); //clear WM_MOUSEMOVE
    while (GetMessage(&Msg,0, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: [Согласно MSND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762098(v=vs.85).aspx) вы должны заменить `WndProc` и `DefWindowProc` на `ScreenSaverProc` и `DefScreenSaverProc` соответственно. Да и вообще, вы делаете не по [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144066(v=vs.85).aspx).